# How to update database table with table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, pyodbc

I have a **SQL Server** table with columns including `Ticket id`, and each row corresponding to one ticket.

Weekly, I will pull data with the same columns with rows corresponding to all tickets that have been created or changed since the last pull.

My question is, what is the correct SQL command to update my existing table so that the new tickets are added and the changed tickets are updated?

Apologies, I am new to SQL. I will be using `pyodbc` in python with a db in SQL Server.

Edit: Ok, for anyone still looking at this, my question becomes: how can one upsert/MERGE a large json to sql server table using `pyodbc`?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use a `MERGE` or an Upsert (a portmanteau of `UPDATE` and `INSERT`), where you `UPDATE` the table and then `INSERT` the new data. A search of these terms will give you a wealth of resources.

Comment: in a database table, a column is called `field` ... a row are called `record`

Comment: @jsotola , thanks for the lingo, appreciate it.

Comment: No, they're not, @jsotola ... There is no such thing as a field or record in SQL Server... They are rows and columns. RLS doesn't mean "record level security" and you don't `GRANT`/`DENY` a `USER` permissions on a `FIELD`.

Comment: @Larnu Seems like Merge is exactly what I want to do, thanks for the input. Seems like I will probably have to make a new table in my db first instead of keeping my incremental data as a json in pyton. I hope this is not a problem/too costly

Comment: Well now I don't know who to believe

Comment: ....Probably @Larnu

Comment: The documentation, @DavisW . For starters [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't contain the word "field" once, but "column" appears 458 times; because a table contains **columns** not "fields".

Comment: @Larnu you've convinced me. Let's shun jsotola

Comment: I wouldn't say "shun" them, @DavisW , it's just incorrect advice. A record can mean different things, depending on the data and person. For example, a "client record", might include data from several tables and rows; the client's telephone numbers might be in a different table, and each one on a different row. Same for their emails. In some environments, the whole thing would be defined as the "client record" as the end user probably consumes all this information on a single screen. This can mean that referring to a row as a "record" can be confusing as it doesn't always mean a row.

Comment: @Larnu is *more* correct, but don't fall into the trap of arguing terminology because it is mostly a waste of time. If you're talking about a table and you mention one of its "records" then people will know what you mean. Besides, strictly speaking, relational databases don't have "tables" and "rows", anyway; they have "relations" and "tuples" (at least according to the pedants out there). :)

Comment: Ok..... tomato tomato, my b. @jsotola, you are officially unshunned. Thank you all for your help